# Ip address redirect to Domain name using .htaccess on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my IP address to my domain name using .htaccess file but it doesn't seems to be working . Along with this i would like to redirect my https link to http site as well. Can anyone help .

my .htaccess file looks like this

---

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /

<FilesMatch "\.inc.php">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>

## SEO Friendly URLs ##
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.11\.111\.11$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^(admin)($|/) - [L]
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this on shared hosting. The whole idea of shared hosting is that you share the same machine and it's IP address(es) with multiple other websites. Unless your hosting provider allows you to "claim" this IP address (which only they can help you do), it cannot be done. If it could be done, that would also mean that all the other website owners that share your IP could do what you are doing. Where is the server going to redirect the visitor then?

Because of this reason, changing your .htaccess file won't help anything at all. The server configuration that is managed by your hosting provider overrules this. Some hosting providers allow the option to buy a dedicated IP address or usually if you buy an SSL certificate from them it comes with one. Other than that, there are no options you have.